# Complex Cursors for returning multiple rows

Tags: sql, plsql, cursor

Each row in a cursor should be joined with another table and the whole result should be returned a one cursor

Say cursor1 return 5 rows.
Each of these 5 rows should be joined with table1.
and the final result for all the 5 rows should be returned a 1 row.

Plz help

Comment: So you want the five rows from cursor1 joined to appropriate rows from table1, then you want the rows resulting from the join concatenated together into a giant single row?  Is that correct?

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking for.  Some sample input data and expected output would be really helpful.  It doesn't have to be the full dataset, a simple test case using EMP and DEPT would do it.

Comment: If you change the word "cursor" for resultset, it becomes simpler. Its just a join, and an inline view would probably do. How about posting the code (or a stripped down version of it, at least)

Answer (score 1):

It is rather tricky to combine the fetched records from a ref cursor with the result set of another query.  A much better idea would be to open just the one ref cursor with a SELECT which joins all the relevant tables.

Comment: Columns in the cursor after joing 5 tables employeeID, employeename, nativeplace,permanentplace, presentplace, etc ......
Table B: employeeid, employeename, place, phone,zip,street,etc...

Finally we should return one cursor, after joining the cursor result and table B result based on empid and empname. 

Is it possible to return one cursor? 

Plz help

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't clear, but it sounds like what you need is something like this

a) Define an object type with the shape of your result row
   b) Define a collection of that object type
   c) Create a function with a return type of the collection type - this could take in cursor A as a parameter (SYS_REFCURSOR), join each row in cursor A to table B, and then use PIPE ROW for each result row.
   d) If the final result is needed as a cursor, then another function along the lines of

```
 FUNCTION complex_query(in_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR) 
 RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
 IS
     lreturn SYS_REFCURSOR;
 BEGIN
     OPEN lreturn FOR
        (SELECT * FROM TABLE(convert_to_collection(in_cursor)));
     RETURN lreturn;
 END;
```

Alternatively, you could just do the SELECT * FROM TABLE(convert_to_collection(in_cursor)) directly.

What I don't understand is the requirement that everything is returned as 1 row.